# In Flink, how to convert the cumulative value into an incremental value in flink and then aggregate by some keys

Tags: sql, aggregate, apache-flink, batch-processing, flink-streaming

How to convert the cumulative value into an incremental value in flink (some keys are considered to be a user, and then the cumulative value becomes the incremental value of two adjacent ones), and then on the basis of the incremental value (time Dimension, a key) for aggregation (sum)

For example, origin data is:

time A B value

0 1 1 1

0 2 2 2

0 1 1 4

0 2 2 3

1 1 1 5

1 2 2 6

After convert to incremental value, we got

time A B value

0 1 1 1

0 2 2 2

0 1 1 3

0 2 2 1

1 1 1 2

1 2 2 3

Then we aggregate by (time, A), got final result is

time A value

0 1 4

0 2 3

1 1 2

1 2 3

Is there a program that can do these two things at once?
One solution is to use session window or global window to convert the original table into an incremental table and store it in another place, and start another task to aggregate the results? But this will consume additional storage.

Sorry for my poor english and thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to have two separate applications, or to store anything. Just let the output of the first step flow into the second step. Conceptually that's

```java
results = input
  .somehowDoTheIncrementalPart()
  .thenAggregate();
```

or in SQL you could use a nested query, something like

```sql
SELECT ts, sum(diff) FROM ( 
  SELECT ts, userId, diff 
  FROM events 
  MATCH_RECOGNIZE ( 
    PARTITION BY id 
    ORDER BY ts 
    MEASURES 
      p2.v - p1.v AS diff, p2.id AS userId, p2.ts AS ts 
    AFTER MATCH SKIP TO LAST p2 
    PATTERN (p1 p2) 
    DEFINE p1 AS TRUE, p2 AS TRUE )
) GROUP BY ts, userId
```